# What are some good R coding practices when it comes to converting for loops to something more refined?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to level up my R coding skills and I think this would be a good first step. Right now, I'm struggling with how to use R to efficiently convert for loop blocks into dplyr or other library functions. For example, I have the following table

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 |

normally I would do something like

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  row = df[, i];
  if(row$col1[i] == 1){
     row$col3[i] = 2;
     row$col2[i] = row$col1[i] + row$col3[i];
     row$col1[i] = 12;
  }
  else if(row$col1[i] == 2){
    row$col3[i] = row$col2[i] * 10;
    row$col2[i] = 10;
    row$col1[i] = 100;
  }
  else{
    row$col3[i] = 8;
    row$col2[i] = row$col1[i] - row$col3[i];
    row$col1[i] = 5;
  }
  df[, i] = row;
}
```

but I feel like there is a better way to do this. I know you could do dplyr::mutate and change ifelse statements, but since they all share ifelse statements, I don't want to write them multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

We may create some logical expressions and update as vectorized assignments instead of looping over each row (assuming there are more rows)

```
i1 <- df$Col1 == 1
i2 <- df$Col1 == 2
i3 <- !(i1|i2)
df[i1, ] <- list(12, rowSums(df[i1, c("Col1", "Col3")]), 2)
df[i2, ] <- list(100, 10, df$Col2[i2] * 10)
df[i3, ] <- list(5, df$Col1[i3] - df$Col3[i3], 8)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it if there were more columns? I'm assuming that if there were more columns, you would have to create a list for each of the columns. Also, does this handle ifelse? I should've done a better example but in the case that there is overlap in the else if statement with the first one, wouldn't it write over the correct values?

Comment: @Tigertron your conditions involve replacement in more than one column i.e. the reason I used this